# PhpStorm 2020.1 does not react to Chrome Xdebug extension

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm running Xdebug 2.9 on my Mac and I'm able to debug a PHP script inside PhpStorm 2020.1, but I can't get the IDE to react to Chrome Xdebug extension when I set a breakpoint in a simple script that I run on the browser.

I activated the extension (it's green) and I've set `PHPSTORM` as the IDE key in the extension options, and I'm listening for PHP debug connections but still PhpStorm does not react to it.

I have set the following in my php.ini file also :

> debug.remote_enable = 1

I don't know what to configure more than that.

**EDIT :** I use MAMP for PHP on the web. The solution was to uncomment the "zend_extension" key in the php.ini of my MAMP php version instead of pointing to my own xdebug extension.

Comment: All what such browser extension does is sets the Xdebug cookie that will be sent with the next request to the server. 1) Check that the cookie is set (use Network tat of your Developer Tools in browser to see what is sent) 2) Check you `phpinfo();` output captured via browser -- it's common on Mac and Linux to have separate php.ini files for CLI and web server. You may have Xdebug enabled for CLI but not for web. 3) If all good -- provide the whole Xdebug section from `phpinfo()` output and collect and share Xdebug log -- you may have different config values to what PhpStorm uses.

Comment: @LazyOne, I don't have any xdebug section on the phpinfo output. I use MAMP for the PHP web version. I've set both php.ini files, for web and cli versions the same

Comment: If you do not have Xdebug section in `phpinfo()` output then Xdebug extension is not installed/loaded. Try restarting your MAMP. You **need** to confirm that Xdebug is there and has configured options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following ini config:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart = off
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

And here is my PHPSTORM config:
[image]
[image]

**P.S.:** but it does not work for cli request. To enable debug for cli request you should set:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
```